Existence of $n$ where $S_b(n^k) \equiv r \pmod{M}$ where $S_b$ denotes sum of digits in base $b$
Let $b, k, M \in \mathbb{N} \setminus \{1\}$, $r \in \{0, 1, \dots M-1\}$ and $S_b: \mathbb{N}_0 \rightarrow \mathbb{N}_0 $ denote the method which outputs the sum of digits of its input in base $b$.
Then does there exist $n \in \mathbb{N}_0$, s.t., $$
S_b(n^k) \equiv r \pmod{M}
$$
Context
I was experimenting to find insights on this problem, which is for $k=3, b=10$, and found out in code that for $2 \le r \le 7$ and $M=9$, there doesn't exist any $n \le 10^8$ satisfying the above. I found this to be very odd as I assumed there shouldn't be any pattern like this for any $k$. I also can't prove this for all $n$.
I understand proving/ find a solution for the general case might be too difficult, so I would accept any answer on more specific cases like above. Best case scenario would be an algo which outputs true/false given $b, j, r, M$.
Edit to add some code results
Ran some code for all $n \le 10^6$, and found the below list of $k,b,M,r$ for which there didn't exist any $n$ satisfying the condition. Its formatted like $k \;\; b \;\; M \;\; \{r_1, r_2, \dots\}$ on each line.
2 4 3 {2}
2 4 6 {2, 5}
2 4 9 {2, 5, 8}
2 5 4 {2, 3}
2 5 8 {2, 3, 6, 7}
2 6 5 {2, 3}
2 6 10 {2, 3, 7, 8}
2 7 3 {2}
2 7 6 {2, 5}
2 7 9 {2, 5, 8}
2 8 7 {3, 5, 6}
2 9 4 {2, 3}
2 9 8 {2, 3, 5, 6, 7}
2 10 3 {2}
2 10 6 {2, 5}
2 10 9 {2, 3, 5, 6, 8}
3 5 4 {2}
3 5 8 {2, 6}
3 8 7 {2, 3, 4, 5}
3 9 4 {2}
3 9 8 {2, 4, 6}
3 10 9 {2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7}
4 4 3 {2}
4 4 6 {2, 5}
4 4 9 {2, 5, 8}
4 5 4 {2, 3}
4 5 8 {2, 3, 6, 7}
4 6 5 {2, 3, 4}
4 6 10 {2, 3, 4, 7, 8, 9}
4 7 3 {2}
4 7 6 {2, 5}
4 7 9 {2, 5, 8}
4 8 7 {3, 5, 6}
4 9 4 {2, 3}
4 9 8 {2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7}
4 10 3 {2}
4 10 6 {2, 5}
4 10 9 {2, 3, 5, 6, 8}
5 5 4 {2}
5 5 8 {2, 6}
5 9 4 {2}
5 9 8 {2, 4, 6}
5 10 9 {3, 6}

Edit 2: found some interesting relations $\pmod{b-1}$
Ran some code and verified $$
S_b(n^k) \equiv n^k \pmod{b-1}
$$
The above is actually easy to prove for $k=1$ (use the $n = \sum d_ib^i$ expansion in base $b$), but I can't see a way to tackle it for later cases.
Using this, we can check for the case $M = b-1$ by checking the possible $r$ values for $n \in \mathbb{Z}_{b-1}$. Also it seems like if $\gcd(M, b-1) = 1$, then we can get a possible $n$ for all $r$ values. The key point seems to be in the proof of the above relation.
